# How to subtract $(101110.01)_2$ from $(110011.10)_2$?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

**My attempt:**

[image]

My answer is wrong. The correct answer is [101.01](https://math-physics-calc.com/binary-calculator):

[image]

---

I don't understand why I'm getting the wrong answer here. The problem seems to be in this column:

[image]

If I get a $0$ as the result there in that column, then everything will be good, but $1-0=1$, how can I get a $0$ there?

Comment: Have you tried “subtraction by borrowing”? Start from the rightmost column and work your way left.

Comment: Consider the "critical" part i.e. the leftmost 4 digit: 1100 minus 1011. When you "borrow" (recall usual subtraction) you get 10(10)0 where (10) is 2. Then you borrow again and you get 101(10) because you have borrowed from (10) i.e. 2 a unit and the result left is 1 i.e. 1. The final result will be 101(10) minus 1011 that amount to 0001 because (10)-1 is 2-1=1.

Comment: The machinery is similar to computing 100-99. The first step is producing 0(10)0-099 and the second step will be 09(10)-099=001.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I edited the question to show the carry.

Comment: When you borrow carry to subtract from $100$ number $011$, then you obtain $001$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't borrow from $0$, so you need to go one column further. Now the $1$ in column 7 (numbering from the right) becomes $0$ and in column 6 you have $(10)$ from which you can borrow $1$ to do column 5.

After that you have $1$ in column 6 and $0$ in column 7.

But it's much simpler if you add the complement (I'll omit the period that can be just reinserted at the end). The complement is $01000110$ and you add
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
11001110 & + \\
01000110 \\
\hline
100010100
\end{array}
$$
You then remove the highest bit and add $1$ to get
$$
10101
$$
Why is this so? We have computed
$$
x=11001110+(11111111-10111001)=11001110+(100000000-1-10111001)
$$
and therefore
$$
11001110-10111001=x-100000000+1
$$